# how to get Flink cluster leader?

Tags: apache-flink

use zookeeper as Flink cluster high-availability, the cluster has 3 JobManager, how to get Flink cluster leader? i want to submit/cancel/stop the job through the leader's IP address

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to retrieve the leading JobManager from your cluster for this purpose. As long as all JobManagers are connected to your Zookeeper quorum, you should be able to submit/cancel/stop your job using any of the JobManagers.